# What does "金三 2:33" mean in etymology?

Tags: etymology

In the *뉴에이스 국어사전* included with the iOS/MacOS Dictionary app, I noticed the etymology for the word `함부로` showed:

> 〔➙ᄒᆞᆫ보로(金三 2:33)＞함부로〕

What does the `金三 2:33` mean?

Looking up the [same word in Naver](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=41643500), it shows:

> 어원 : ＜보로＜금강경삼가해(1482)＞

I notice the `금` and `삼` in there, so guessing they are possibly related to the `金` and `三` respectively. Is this a way of representing dates, perhaps based on the royal calendar? I've seen things in museums that say something like, "the 3rd year of King Sejeong." Is this related?

Comment: 금강경삼가해(金剛經三家解) is a movable type printing in ancient Korean. First initiated by 세조, later  edited and published under the order of 세조비(世祖妃). https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/금강경삼가해_권2

Comment: Dictionaries typically include a list of used abbreviations in the prefix or appendix.  That is, the physical book of 뉴에이스 국어사전 should include a table of references containing "金三 -> 금강경삼가해".  It might be missing in the app version.

Answer (score 5):

It's the abbreviated name of the book "금강경삼가해" that the old form "ᄒᆞᆫ보로" appeared in. 2:33 means the word appears in Page 33, Volume 2.

금강경삼가해 means it's a side-by-side translation of the three explanations of the Buddhist text "The Diamond Sutra"(금강경).

Technically it isn't itself the etymology of the word, but an indication of single use in a corpus. Determining an etymology needs extensive researches, but majority of 15th-century Korean literature written in 한문 are not telling much about how the Korean words that time are used in practice. Dictionaries 
instead quote manuscripts side-commented with old Korean translations, (usually with titles suffixed with ~가해, ~언해, etc.,) but there are no more than few dozens of them left.

Comment: @puzzlet your edit has been added to Mujjin's answer for now, but I request Mujjin to comment on whether the edit actually improves the answer.

Comment: @puzzlet if you have a significant amount of new content to add, I think it would be better to post a separate answer.